# treeview node is highlighted even i did not right click on the node

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I am working on a winform and on my UI there is a treeview, I found that the treenode will be highlighted even I did not click on the node by right mouse (eg, Node1 will be highlighted when I click on the following position), but i really do not like this behavior because I want to show a different context menu when I did not click on a treenode

> +RootNode
>
> ```
>   |_ Node1                [ Right Click Here, Node1 will be highlighted]
>   |
>   |_ Node2                [ Right Click Here, Node2 will be highlighted]
> ```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I understand your question. You mean that if you click to the empty space to the right of a node, the node remains highlighted as long as you're holding down the right mouse button?

Comment: yes, you are right! I do not want the node to be highlighted when I did not click on the node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another method to prevent the node to be highlight when the user not click on the node, and I only set the BackColor and ForeColor for each of the node when adding it to the tree

```
newNode.BackColor = treeview1.BackColor;
newNode.ForeColor = treeview1.ForeColor;
treeview1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

Then in the MouseDown event, set the SelectedNode property as following

```
 private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
        TreeNode Node = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.Location);
        if (Node != null && Node.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
            treeView1.SelectedNode = Node;
        else
            treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
 }
```

Comment: I suppose this works, except that you still see the selection rectangle on the node while you're holding down the mouse button. It doesn't fill in the selection rectangle (because you've changed the `BackColor`), but the dotted outline is still there. But I suppose that unless you're the obsessive perfectionist that I am, this will work fine. :-)

Comment: @Code Gray: I did not see the dotted outline if i did not click on the node

Answer (score 4):

Going off of your comment to Kevin Wienhold's answer, you just want to allow the user to click in the empty space of the treeview and deselect any selected node.

**You can do this by handling the [`MouseDown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) of the `TreeView` control, and setting the [`SelectedNode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx) to `null` if the mouse was clicked over a location that does not contain a node.** For example, you could use the following code:

```
private void myTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (myTreeView.HitTest(e.Location).Node == null)
    {
        myTreeView.SelectedNode = null;
    }
}
```

This takes advantage of the [`HitTest` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sb88bz.aspx) to determine which node is located at a particular point, specifying the location of the mouse event as the point to test. You don't need any other code to select nodes as usual when the user *does* click on them; that is handled automatically by the `TreeView`.

---

**EDIT:** As my comment to the question indicates, I'm still exceptionally unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish here. If you're actually interested in preventing a node from being temporarily highlighted while you hold down the right mouse button in the empty space to the side of the node, things get a little more complex.

I've looked into this problem before, and the tricky part is that window messages are not received while the mouse button is being held down, at least not until the mouse is moved (in which case, the node is no longer selected anyway). This behavior is apparently dictated by the operating system and not easily overridden using the standard .NET-provided events. You can try to cancel a click of the right button in the `MouseDown` event all day long, but the node is being selected by Windows before this event is ever raised in your control (remember that .NET-provided controls like the `TreeView` and `ListView` are simply wrappers around those same controls provided by the Windows API, which apparently implements this "select-node-while-right-button-held-down" behavior itself).

What *does* work, however, is overriding [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) in a derived `TreeView` control, and handling the [`WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646242%28VS.85%29.aspx). But notice that even setting the `SelectedNode` property to `null` doesn't work here, because that's not processed until *after* Windows automatically selects the node as a response to the right mouse button being clicked—no matter what you do, you have to prevent the base `TreeView` control from receiving the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message. So, you have a couple of choices in how to handle this:

1. You can simply cancel the right-click message by bailing out early with a `return` statement. Of course, this means you're not going to be able to handle this event in your `MouseDown` handler, because it's never actually passed to the control! So if you want to show a pop-up context menu, this probably won't work for you.

   ```
   public class NewTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   {
       protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
       {
           const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
           if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
           {
               return;
           }
           base.WndProc(ref m);
       }   
   }
   ```
2. You can show your context menu in the overridden `WndProc` method as a response to the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message, and then `return` from the method without allowing the base class to handle the message. This does the exact same thing as the first solution (prevents the right-click event from causing the node to appear selected), but it does allow you to show a context menu (or do anything else that you want) whenever the right-click occurs. Of course, it does mean that all of the relevant code will have to be contained within your subclass of the `TreeView` control, not handled in your form's UI code, which may or may not be convenient for you.

   ```
   public class NewTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   {
       protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
       {
           const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
           if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
           {
               //Create and show a context menu
               var myContextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
               myContextMenu.Items.Add("First Item");
               myContextMenu.Items.Add("Second Item");
               return;
           }
           base.WndProc(ref m);
       }   
   }
   ```
3. You could [raise your *own*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx) `RightMouseClick` event from your custom `TreeView` class as a response to the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message, which you could then handle as you wish from your form's UI code. By not passing the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message to the base `TreeView` control class, this accomplishes the same goal as the previous two suggestions, but allows you to handle the right-button click event in your form's UI code instead of having to put all of your logic into the subclassed control's `WndProc`.

   ```
   public class NewTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   {
       protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
       {
           const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
           if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
           {
               //Raise your custom event
               OnRightMouseClick(new EventArgs());
               return;
           }
           base.WndProc(ref m);
       }   
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 : for Hit test but Hit test will still show the node , have you tested your solution ?

Comment: @Saurabh: Yup, tested and works just fine. I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm not using `HitTest` to deselect the node, I'm determining which node the mouse was clicked over, and if it was not clicked over a node, setting the `SelectedNode` property to `null`, which *does* cause the node to be deselected. Unless by "show" the node, you mean it doesn't *remove* the node from the `TreeView`, in which case, no, but that's not what is being asked for.

Comment: @Code gray : Added one more solution based upon Hittesting

Comment: I also tried this but the node highlighted until I released the right click.

Comment: As I commented to the question initially, I was very unclear on what was exactly being asked. My reading of the asker's comment to Kevin Wienhold's question seemed to suggest that my first solution was the answer. The last few comments argue otherwise, so I've updated my answer with some other ideas.

Comment: @Cody Gray: If you're actually interested in preventing a node from being temporarily highlighted while you hold down the right mouse button in the empty space to the side of the node, things get a little more complex. ---- This is what i want

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        TreeViewHitTestInfo h = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);

        if (h.Location != TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label && h.Location!= TreeViewHitTestLocations.None )
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see what you're saying now, but assuming the asker wants to stop the node from appearing selected *while the right mouse button is held down*, this won't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want no node to be selected if the user clicks into empty space within the TreeView.
You could accomplish that by handling the MouseDown-Event of the Tree and setting the tree's SelectedNode property to TreeView.GetNodeAt(e.Location).

Comment: Yes, I do not want any node is highlighted when the user clicks into empty space within the treeview, and I have tried your code but it does not work

Comment: @Carlos_Liu: I'm surprised it doesn't work for you, I just tried it myself and it seems to work fine.

Comment: On second thought, if you have FullRowSelect set to true, GetNodeAt will return a node, even if the mousecursor is beside the text. Maybe this might explain the problem you're having?

Comment: the node will not be highlighted when you right click on the empty space to the right of a node on your computer?