# About treeview control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have used the mouse down event of the treeview control. And I want to set the selected node as the node on which the mouse down event has happened. How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: The `TreeView` control *automatically* selects the node the user clicks on with the mouse.

Comment: @Cody Gray:In my application when i'm clicking right mouse button that time it  is not selecting that node as selected node it select the previously selected node for the further operation. but i want the node on which user right clicks but which may or may not be selected by the user. Then is it possible?

Comment: Did you try Bradley's solution? You can implement it at a lower level than that if need be, but his is by far the *simplest* solution.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes i tried that code but AfterSelect event is only occurring on clicking Left mouse button click & not by clicking right mouse button . And i want to check for the right mouse button.

Comment: @Cody He's right, for whatever reason, the right mouse button doesn't select nodes in a `TreeView`. Doesn't seem like conventional Windows behaviour, must be a WinForms quirk.

Comment: @Bradley: Yeah, it might very well be a bug in the WinForms implementation. I created my own custom TreeView control long ago that fixed a ton of one-off bugs, so I've forgotten most of the problems that might be lurking. I can think of a couple different solutions, they might be overkill, but I suppose I'll post them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options come to mind here. Both might well be overkill, but they still solve the problem.

1. Handle the `MouseDown` event and use the [`HitTest` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest.aspx) to determine which node the user clicked on. If they clicked on a valid node, manually set the focus to that node via the [`SelectedNode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx).

   ```
   private void myTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
       {
           myTreeView.SelectedNode = myTreeView.HitTest(e.Location).Node;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The bazooka-style solution is to override the `WndProc` method and listen for [`WM_RBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646242.aspx) messages. I've done this in my own extended version of the `TreeView` control because it allows me to fix some really minor stuff that normal, non-obsessive people probably wouldn't notice. I go into [excruciating detail in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333093/treeview-node-is-highlighted-even-i-did-not-right-click-on-the-node/4333264#4333264).

   Basically, you're doing the same thing as the code above does, but at a lower level, which stops the native control from pulling some shenanigans with the focus. I don't remember if they actually apply here (hence the potential overkill), but I'm too lazy to fire up Visual Studio to see for sure.

   ```
   public class FixedTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
   {
       protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
       {
           const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
           if (m.Msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
           {
               Point mousePos = this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
               this.SelectedNode = this.GetNodeAt(mousePos);
           }
           base.WndProc(ref m);
       }   
   }
   ```

The first method should work just fine for you. Try that before breaking out bigger weapons.

Answer (score 2):

The `MouseDown` event is fired before the node is selected. Try handling the `AfterSelect` event instead. If `e.Action` is set to `TreeViewAction.ByMouse` then the event was raised by the mouse.

Comment: But i want to check whether right mouse button is clicked or not because i want to do some further operation depending on which mouse button is clicked. Then what should i do in that case?

Comment: If that's what you really want to do, you must use the `MouseDown` event and the call the `HitTest` method to get the node under the mouse pointer. You can then assign that node (if any) to the `SelectedNode` property.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got my exact result by using HitTest method.